# How to get the 3rd word from a text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help on the query for getting the 3rd word from a text in SQL Server?
The below query retrieves the 2nd word, but I need the 3rd word. Thanks.

```
SELECT substring(@sentence,charindex(' ',@sentence), CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(SUBSTRING(@sentence,charindex(' ',@sentence),LEN(@sentence)-charindex(' ',@sentence)))) )
```

Comment: Ideally, by not using SQL Server, if I am honest. It's string manipulation is terrible at best. If   you have any kind of grammar in your sentences, then you're going to have a really difficult time. For example, from the sentence `'It was then, he realised, he'd f**cked up.'` you could likely end up with the "word" `'then,'` (with the trailing comma).

Comment: SQL Server and PostgreSQL are different products. What you ask though would have problems in *all* database products. Why are you trying to search for words in the middle of a field? It matters. You may be able to use full text search indexes or need the `STRING_SPLIT` method. Or, more likely, you need to redesign your tables to store different values in different rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of JSON you can get the 3rd word

```
Select * 
      ,NewVal = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ,'$[2]')
 From YourTable
```

Or for something a little more robust, use a CROSS APPLY

```
Select A.*
      ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ( '["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ) ) B(JS)
```

If using a variable

```
 Declare @sentence varchar(max) = 'This is only a test'
 Select JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(string_escape(@sentence,'json'),' ','","')+'"]' ,'$[2]')
```